# How do I add an image placeholder to fix this bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner programmer. I'm building my first project which shows a list of my favorite athletes and when clicked the "show" page loads an image of them, their name, and weight.

Overall when adding a new athlete everything works fine. If I decide to add a new athlete and skip adding an image I get this error "Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass", it also highlights my code "<%= image_tag(@fighter.image) %>" that's in my show.html.erb

I've tried adding an alt: but I get another error of "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)".

I've searched for answers and one thread mentioned my controller page and the params section. I did notice that (:image) is preceded by "params.require" which I would assume could be the problem if I'm not adding an element that is required. How do I solve this issue? What would be the best way to add a placeholder, I've added a default.png in my images folder.

Thank you

[show.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrlUk.png)

[fighters_controller.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKwnx.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **ActiveStorage** for uploading athlete images. You can check if an image was attached to your model with `@fighter.image.attached?`.
So I would suggest wrapping the `image_tag` in an IF-clause like so:

```
<% if @fighter.image.attached? %> 
 <%= image_tag(@fighter.image) %>
<% else %>
 <%= image_tag("default.png") %>
<% end %>
```

If you're using **Paperclip** then try the following:

```
<% if @fighter.image.exists? %>
 <%= image_tag(@fighter.image) %>
<% else %>
 <%= image_tag("default.png") %>
<% end %>
```

With **Carrierwave** use:

```
<% if @fighter.image.present? %>
 <%= image_tag(@fighter.image) %>
<% else %>
 <%= image_tag("default.png") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using ActiveStorage, I used your above code into my show.html.erb and now I'm getting "undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Does the show action in your fighters_controller.rb set `@fighter`? Like so

```def show
  @fighter = Fighter.find params[:id] 
end
```

Comment: I didn't have that code in my controller, I added it, still no luck.  Now I'm getting "The asset "N/A" is not present in the asset pipeline."